# Blazor ErrorBoundary not displaying/triggering for exceptions within an async call

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

I've added `<ErrorBoundary>` around the `@Body` within my `Shared/MainLayout.razor` file, yet when an error occurs in an `async` method the default `blazor-error-ui` element in `Pages/_Layout.cshtml` is displayed.

Error example, if I have the following in the razor.cs of a page `<ErrorBoundary>` will trigger as expected:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            int test0 = 0;
            int test = 9 / test0;
            GetCustomer();
        }
```

However the majority of my methods are asynchronous dealing with APIs and waiting for data to load etc. So the following is not causing `<ErrorBoundary>` to trigger, but is caught just fine by `Pages/_Layout.cshtml` `blazor-error-ui`.

```
protected async override void OnInitialized()
        {
            int test0 = 0;
            nt test = 9 / test0;
            await GetCustomer();
        }
```

Also while investigating this I've found that a method called within the page can just fail silenty and not report and error even in the console. (I have `DetailedErrors` set to true)

```
private void SomeButtonClick()
        {
            int test0 = 0;
            int test = 9 / test0;
        }
```

Is it possible the have the `<ErrorBoundary>` trigger from any error, as I don't want the page components to load only partially if any error occurs ?

Comment: Please include the error and where/what it is coming from.

Comment: I've updated my question, while debugging I've found one issue to be that the error boundary doesn't trigger for exceptions which occur within an async call.

Comment: No async is fine looking at my other screen. Async void maybe the issue though. Change it to `async Task` or better still `async ValueTask`

Comment: Weirdly, if I change any of my "async void" methods to "async Task" (and have e.g. the divide by zero code) neither error boundary or blazor-error-ui is triggered. The exception is thrown in VS if I have CLREs on, but the page sits loaded up to that point, and doesn't indicate anything went wrong, other than the missing data/elements its not loaded due to the exception stopping progression.